# How do I navigate to a specific Screen instead of the one I came from when using the back gesture, back softkey or back button in the navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have an App where the user submits some data on **Screen B**, when the request is successfull the App navigates to a **Screen C**, which shows a summary of the submitted data. This **Screen C** is also available from other **Screens X and Y**.

The behaviour I want to introduce is as follows:

- When a User submitted data through **Screen B** and than goes back, either by using the back gesture, pressing the back hardware button (softkey) or pressing the button in the Navigationbar, the App should navigate to a **Screen A**, instead of **Screen B**
- If the user access **Screen C** from **Screen X**, the back functionality should execute the default behaviour and take the User back to **Screen X or Y** respectively.

How do I achieve this behaviour? It should work in both Android and iOS.

This is my current code in **Screen C**:

```
useEffect(() => {
  navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', e => {
    if(cameFrom == 'ScreenB' ){
      e.preventDefault()
      navigation.dispatch({
        ...CommonActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          routes: [{name: 'ScreenA'}],
        }),
      })
    }
    }
  )
```

}, [])

This causes a `Maximum call stack size exceeded.` error.

I have also tried this approach:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(cameFrom == 'ScreenB' ){
      const { routes } = navigation.getState();

      const filteredRoutes = routes.filter(
        route => route.name == 'ScreenA',
      );

     navigation.reset({
       index: filteredRoutes.length - 1,
       routes: filteredRoutes,
     });
   }
 }, [])
```

Taken from [Link](https://dev.to/dimaportenko/going-back-with-gestures-to-a-specific-screen-react-navigation-4ii1), but this executes the navigation to Screen A immediately when Screen C is opened.